# Class 'WP_Post' not found in wp-includes/post.php

Tags: wordpress

I am facing the error 'Class 'WP_Post' not found in wp-includes/post.php' on my website

Provided:
- I have not upgraded wordpress
- I tried replacing wp-includes and wp-admin folders with existing ones. Then 500 error comes.
- class-wp-post.php file is present in 'wp-includes' folder
Please help me into this

Comment: I would reinstall. Use a plugin called `wp clone` to make a back up

Comment: Now there is 2 option according to me replace your source code with backup or upgrade the wordpress. If you are having the backup than only upload those folder which you have replaced.

Comment: Try replacing the wp-includes and wp-admin folder with the same version you had installed prior, you might get the version number from database

Comment: @Deckerz I can't use plugin as this error is also on admin panel.

Comment: @rsakhale tried with your solution...Still it gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check once in `wp-settings.php` if the class name is included within the `require` statement

For reference - https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php

Also, please re-check if `class-wp-post.php` is present in includes folder.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a considerable amount of time on a similar error. Wordpress 4.9.8

Fatal error: Class 'WP_Post' not found in /home/content/42/11706342/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 589 when trying to open image address in browser.

This error was causing images to appear broken in Wordpress and thumbnails to be broken in Image Gallery.

I check the .htaccess file, I disabled plugins, I tried what was suggested here and I manually reupdated Wordpress (v 4.9.8), we tried manually regenerating thumbnails (which I knew wasn't going to work), and more.

Decided to look at .htaccess file one more time and found the issue was a couple of lines there put in by plugin designed to block right-click on images. Reverted to default .htaccess file and everything is working fine now. Shopping for new plugin. Adding here in case it helps someone in the future.